# To check whether a part is present in array of json with loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a array of JSON in which i want to find whether a part of json is present or not.

For eg:
I have this array of json:

```
a = [{'a':'xxxx','b':'yyyy'},{'a':'xzxzxz','b':'asqqqq'}]
```

And I want to know if a = 'xxxx' is present in the array or not?

I have tried this:

```
if {'a':'xxxx'} in a:
    print('1') 
else:
    print('2')
```

But it is giving me '2'

How to do this. Thanks!

P.S: I don't want to use a FOR LOOP

Comment: What you want is to test whether any dict in your list has a key with a specific value; nothing to do with "JSON". `any(d['a'] == 'xxxx' for d in a)`

Comment: First, you have to iterate over every JSON(dict), that's included in your array.
Then you can check, if the dict contains a key and if, check its value.

Comment: @deceze it will raise an exception if `'a'` is not present in the dict

Comment: @Tal If that's a concern, use `d.get('a')` then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any` for testing and I would use `.get` in case not all your `dict` elements have the `a` key, for example this:

```py
a = [{'a':'xxxx','b':'yyyy'},{'a':'xzxzxz','b':'asqqqq'}]

if any(dct.get('a', None) == 'xxxx' for dct in a):
    print(1)
else:
    print(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code prints '2' because `{'a':'xxxx'}` is not present in `a`.
That is because `{'a':'xxxx','b':'yyyy'}` is not equal to `{'a':'xxxx'}`.

You will have to write a function like this:

```py
def has_a(array):
    for item in array:
        if item.get('a') == 'xxxx':
            return True
    return False
```

and then use it like this:

```py
if has_a(a):
    print('1') 
else:
    print('2')
```

Comment: I dont want to use a for loop. How to do it without using a loop?

Comment: @harshit You'll have to loop in one way or another, even if that loop can be dressed up in various ways.

Comment: well, @deceze gave you the best solution. may I ask why don't you want to use a for loop?